# Publish spreadsheet as Atom/RSS not possible in Google Apps for Business

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, rss, atom

I am trying to publish a Google spreadsheet as an RSS feed using Google Chrome. When I go to *File* → *Publish to web* and then go to **Get a link to the published data**, the option *Atom/RSS feed* is not listed.

When I try to use my personal Gmail account, this feature is visible but when I use the business one it does not work. Also, please note that I am the admin of the account so I don't think it is an issue of rights.

Can you tell me how to publish it as an Atom/RSS feed, please?

Comment: You would need to create a script to export XML data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670338/exporting-from-google-spreadsheet-to-xml

Comment: I can try this but what I don't understand is how the normal personal gmail, the sheets have this Atom/Rss feature but the business one does not have..

Comment: Ah, didn't know it was possible in personal accounts, but you are indeed right. Maybe you should clarify your question, e.g. "This works in my personal account, but why is it not possible in Google Apps for business"?

Comment: This is also reported in the Google Docs forums: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/4bK-OI09lvA

Comment: Ohh!! So it is a problem of Google. Thanks for clarifying. Will call google and let you know their answer.

Comment: Do you have any news?

Comment: Looks like they removed the feature everywhere. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Only the older spreadsheets that were not been migrated yet could be published as RSS.

It's worth to say that older spreadsheets will be migrated over 2015. See [Upgrading older spreadsheets to new Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6082736?hl=en) for further details.